# Application of Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can we prove, if $f:\mathbb{D}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{D}^2$ is a homeomorphism then $f(S^1)=S^1$ and $f(\textrm{int}(\mathbb{D}^2))=\textrm{int}(\mathbb{D}^2)$, using fixed point theorem? I have already solved this problem using fundamental groups, but can we solve this problem using fixed point theorem?

Comment: possible not, because fixed point theorem doesn't hold for many spaces, for which the first statement does, the intuitive reason of this statement is the fact "if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $x$ and $f(x)$ must have homeomorphic neighborhoods"

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious way to do it using the fixed point theorem - the natural way is to consider what happens when you remove a point from the boundary $S^1$, which I suspect is what you mean by "using fundamental groups".

Comment: Yea,  that approach I know, my query is, is it possible to kill this problem using fixed point theorem?

Comment: As in my answer, I can't see any way to do so using the fixed point theorem.